# Physical data location on cloud

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, cloud, cloud-hosting

we are starting a SaaS solution and we need to know the geographical location of the data storage, and ensure that the provider will not store data in a restricted country.

Is this possible on any cloud provider such as Amazon, IBM or Azure ? 
Do you have any experience with this ? 
thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows Azure Trust Center lists the locations of all datacenters, in its [Privacy](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/privacy/) page:

- Asia: East (Hong Kong) and Southeast (Singapore)
- Europe: North (Ireland) and West (Netherlands)
- United States: North Central (Illinois), South Central (Texas), East (Virginia), and West (California)

When deploying your app, you choose the specific datacenter you want. Same goes for your storage accounts and SQL Azure databases.

Answer (score 0):

When you activate/provision various Amazon AWS services you have to select what "region" you want them to run in (US East, US West, Japan, EU, etc)... the specific regions available vary depending on the specific service...

Bottom line you have control over where your data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to David Answer!!

Adding more, most of cloud services providers knows that it could a principle requirement for any customer who choose a cloud service to know first where there data is located and how it is replicated to for retrieval purpose.

Windows Azure guarantees that your data will stay within the geographic location which you setup for your Azure Storage and/or with SQL Azure. With Azure Storage, data in same storage is replicated the other data canter in the same geo location, unless you have enabled CDN service with your Azure Storage. With SQL Azure your data is still stored in same Geo location where you have created your main database, unless you are created multiple databases on other Geo location and using Database Sync.

Look [here](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Where_is_my_data_stored) for Amazon S3 about their S3 data storage locations.